# How to execute this PowerPoint Macro for OBS on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: vba, applescript, powerpoint, obs

This PowerPoint Macro (in Windows) will allow a change of scene in OBS by taking the first four characters in a presentation's notes and parsing them as keystrokes to OBS. E.g. OBS1 will keystroke Control+1 in OBS and thus change the scene according to hotkeys settings.

This macro won't work on Office 365 for Mac as it seems the macro don't have access to any applications. I guess the macro has to be re-written to include AppleScript for this action, or am I wrong?

How would I go about it?

Original macro:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
Dim i As Integer
Dim sNotes As String
Dim sKey As String

i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
s = Left(ActivePresentation.Slides(i).NotesPage.Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text, 4)

If Left(s, 3) = "OBS" Then
sKey = "^" & Right(s, 1)
AppActivate ("OBS")
SendKeys (sKey), 1
AppActivate ("PowerPoint")
End If
End Sub
```

**References:**
Original idea: https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/powerpoint-macro-for-controlling-obs.1061/
AppleScript with VB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/office-mac/applescripttask

Answer (score 0):

I've written python to achieve was Scott Hanselman was [doing](https://github.com/shanselman/PowerPointToOBSSceneSwitcher). You can find my obsPPTXwithPython repository [here](https://github.com/tvanyo/obsPPTXwithPython).

It's not VBA, which I avoid. You'll need to know some python to use this, so sorry if it doesn't help.